# Async Task Freezes UI

Tags: android, listview, uiview, android-asynctask, cursor

I'm facing a problem with my Async task. I have some normal operations to accomplish in the background and view results after it completes however the UI freezes although my code inside the doinbackground block. Please help me!

Hereunder my code.

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(Interface.this, null, "Loading...", true);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

        //

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Executing",
        // 3000).show();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Calculate();

            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pd.dismiss();

    }

}



private void Calculate()

{

    curs = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, MyDbHelper.COL_Common
            + "=" + "?", new String[] { From[xxxto] + From[xxxfrom] },
            null, null, null);
    cursD = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, MyDbHelper.COL_Common
            + "=" + "?", new String[] { From[xxxfrom] + From[xxxto] },
            null, null, null);

    curs.moveToFirst();

    cursD.moveToFirst();

    double selection = curs.getDouble(curs
            .getColumnIndex(MyDbHelper.COL_Currone));

    double selection2 = cursD.getDouble(cursD
            .getColumnIndex(MyDbHelper.COL_Currone));

    Long myNum = Long.parseLong(valval.getText().toString().trim());

    double myNum3 = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.######")
            .format(myNum * selection2));

    valval2.setText(String.valueOf(myNum3));


/*  
    Cursor B = mDb
            .query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, MyDbHelper.COL_CurrFavor
                    + "=? And " + MyDbHelper.COL_Currsecond + "=?",

                    new String[] { "YES", "EUR" }, null, null, null);

    */          

    Cursor B = mDb.rawQuery("select * from "
            + MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME + " where " + MyDbHelper.COL_CurrFavor + " = ? AND  "
            + MyDbHelper.COL_Currsecond + " = ?", new String[] { "YES", "EUR" });




    for (int s = 0; s < 4 - 1; s++)

    {
        B.moveToPosition(s);

        String ZVZV = B.getString(0);

        int BSBS = B.getInt(9);

        Cursor curcur = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns,
                MyDbHelper.COL_Common + "=" + "?",
                new String[] { From[xxxfrom] + From[BSBS - 1] }, null,
                null, null);

        curcur.moveToFirst();

        double calcal = curcur.getDouble(6);

        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

        double formattedNumber = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat(
                "#.######").format(myNum * calcal));

        args.put(MyDbHelper.COL_Currsum, formattedNumber);

        mDb.update(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, args, "_id =" + ZVZV, null);

    }

    cursm.requery();



}
```

Here is the error in the Logcat :

> 12-20 04:41:38.469: E/AndroidRuntime(440): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Also I run it using : new DownloadFileFromURL2().execute("");

Answer (score 7):

**Do not do not do not** do this in `AsyncTask`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
```

every method in `AsyncTask` runs on the `UI Thread` except for `doInBackground()`. Do your work in `doInBackground()` (your calculations, network operations, and such) then get a result from that and update the `UI` in `onProgressUpdate()` by calling `publishProgress()` or, if the background work is completely finished, return a result to `onPostExecute()` and you can update there.

If that doesn't solve your current problem then post how you call the task...hopefully not with `.get()`.

**Edit**

Also, you should look at the Docs again, you aren't actually passing anything to `doInBackground()` but an empty `String` in `.execute()`

```
new DownloadFileFromURL2().execute("");
```

so you could change the first `param` of the declaration to `Void`

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
```

and not pass it anything

```
new DownloadFileFromURL2().execute();
```

unless you were planning on updating this later. You also aren't passing `onPostExecute()` anything from `doInBackground()` with

```
return null;
```

so you could change the `params` it takes. So now we have

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
```

and

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
```

and again you have your `onProgressUpdate()` taking no `params` in your task class declaration (second `param`)

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
```

so it should look like

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage

}
```

Of course those all depend on what you plan on passing them which you will need to pass something to update the `UI` after getting results from your `Calculate()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. I've tried to remove the runnable but I've got en error as attached to the main question.

Comment: Because you haven't removed the `UI` stuff (`Toasts` and such) from the `Calculate()` method

Comment: OK I will try to modify the code depend on the new methodology and remove the unnecessary UI stuff outside the doInbackground. Will update you in a bit :) Thank you fro your help !

Comment: No problem. Remember that when you call from `doInBackground()` you are calling from a background `Thread` so anything you call from there is called from a background `Thread`, inherently.

Answer (score 3):

This is where you are doing it wrong.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Calculate();

            }
        });
```

Here you are calling the `Calculate()` method in the UI thread again. That's why your app freezes. Just call `Calculate()` inside `doInBackground()`.

Comment: No! `Calculate()` does `UI` stuff so this will create more errors doing it from a background `Thread`

Comment: The UI stuff should be removed from that method. And put them inside onProgressUpdate() or onPostExecute()

Answer (score 3):

You are calling Calculate() on UI thread.Which will definitely freezes the UI .
Remove all the Ui stuff from calculate() and call it directly inside Async.